# What is the source of this segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers, g++, segmentation-fault

I've got a bizarre error here: `882 Segmentation fault      ./a.out`

The segment of code:

```
int end=array.Length, loop=0;
cout<<end<<" about to print";
for(;loop<end;loop++){
    cout<<"\nMr. loop says: ";
    array.get(loop).print(fout);
}
```

Output of my program:

```
enpty initializer called for llist
enpty initializer called for entry
adding
adding
999deleting999
done deleting
123deleting123
done deleting
333deleting333
done deleting
printing
2 about to print
./g+: line 7:   882 Segmentation fault      ./a.out
```

and vital output of:

```
printing
2 about to print
./g+: line 7:   882 Segmentation fault      ./a.out
```

meaning that the error is this line:

```
for(;loop<end;loop++){
```

which has proven good values and is syntactically correct (yes I know its bad style, though).

Ideas?  No one at my university seems to be able to help me with this.

here are the files:

- [core.cpp](http://codepad.org/NMRq39xJ)
- [entry.h](http://codepad.org/JjorHzBU)
- [in.data](http://codepad.org/0cpwcvq4)
- [llist.h](http://codepad.org/IcUeYtgD)
- [mmm.h](http://codepad.org/QAw7vAxm)
- [student.h](http://codepad.org/cfULEzlT)

Comment: "No one at my university seems to be able to help me with this"..  Some university!!

Comment: @Josh Are you a student or a teacher? If a student, you should probably tag this question as [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info). If a teacher, you may want to consider switching to a university where someone in the cs department knows what a segmentation fault is.

Comment: I know.  I'm getting out of it after this year...I'm a sophomore and bumping past the professor's and classes knowledge.  It's bad.  There's hardly anything to challage me so  start going off On my own stuff and end up with so many style quirks that people hate my code.

Comment: Put `endl` after all your `cout`s like `cout<<end<<" about to print"<< endl;`. that will flush buffers that won't be flushed when the program crashes.

Comment: Please include a minimal code example in the body of your question and don't require people to visit external sites for essential details about your question.

Comment: Dani got it.  Its at a different line.

Comment: @Josh: Please show a definition for `array` and whatever type `array` is.

Comment: @ Charles ...really?  Go look at core.cpp for the whole main()

Comment: @Josh: Sorry, you may have missed my last comment: please don't require people to visit external sites for essential details about your question. Questions on stackoverflow.com should be self contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're doing low-level memory operations (and you're not doing this in the posted program), a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) is a sign of memory corruption, i.e. you've messed up some coding. Note that the memory corruption typically occurs before the error is triggered. In extreme cases, initial memory corruption and actual segmentation fault can be hours and modules apart.

Your first step should be to run the program in valgrind or gdb to find out the details of the segmentation fault. Also, always compile with at least `gcc -Wall` and take note of every warning - unless you're modifying the compiler, changes are every single warning indicates a bug.

In your case, the error is almost certainly in the implementation of `llist`. There is a number of problems with that implementation:

- Implementations don't belong in .h files, they should be in .cpp files.
- `entry.towardsback` and `entry.towardsfront` are usually called `prev`(ious) and `next` - those names are shorter and easier to distinguish.
- `hold` should probably be called `head`, in accordance with the general naming conventions of linked lists.
- A list of length 0 shouldn't have any entries, i.e. be initialized with `hold == NULL`.
- From line 61 (in `add`):

```
hold->towardsback = node;
hold->towardsback->towardshead = node; // node->towardshead = node;
```

The second line is almost certainly wrong. You probably want to configure `node` first and then just set `hold->towardsback = node;`.

Comment: Dani needs some points thrown her way as well.  Its on the following line.

Comment: Ok, sounds good.  I'll make the changes.  It help when someone will tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should not mark this answer as accepted unless it solves your problem (you may upvote it if you find it helpful though). I think Moo-Juice is closer to the solution than I am.

Comment: For the second part, some of the other code is made to deal with a ring structure, so I don't think that part will work.  In the initialization scenario, a ring is not formed.

Comment: @ phihag I didn't ask everything wrong with my program, just why I was getting a bizarre error.  This person did that.  Anything beyond right now is appreciated greatly, but beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: @Josh Fair point (that person happens to be me :) ) I added another entry about using `gcc -Wall`, which will find many of the issues mentioned in the answers. I admire your initiative in learning and your detailed question. Best wishes from [HHU Düsseldorf](http://www.uni-duesseldorf.de/)!

Answer (score 1):

Its most likely because how you manage your list. You're adding/removing dynamically allocated objects, and pass them by reference. It's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see several issues with a cursory glance over your code.

1. In your entry<> class

   ```
   operator T* () {return &stud;}
   ```

`stud` is already a T*.  You are now returning the address of that pointer, rather than the pointer itself.

1. In your `llist` class

   ```
   if(temp==temp->towardsback){
           delete this;
   ```

Which will, in effect, delete your list class if this condition is true.  Ouch?

Personally, I think you need to start again on your list implementation :)

Comment: I'm teaching myself over here.  Paying for classes I took for free in 10th grade.  I'm working on it!

Comment: @Josh, keep at it mate, I'm sure you'll crack it :)

Comment: With a prof that after 5 semesters of programming, 3 of which used c++, just says that 'Oh, there's this thing called inheritence'--its disheartening...

Answer (score 0):

I work mostly with c#, but are arrays 0 index in c++?  So, you would need to set end to array.Length-1.   At least in c#, the first element in the array would be array[0].

Comment: `loop<end` means stop short of what the length returned.

Comment: His for loop does less-than on the length of the array, so he has no need to do `length - 1`.